# How to perform multiple calculations with in a single query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a situation where in i have to get the data from an Year Ago , Previous Month and Current Month. What is the best way to achieve this ?

I have a table which contains the year,month and data in it. In the below query have added a filter
 c.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @12MonthsAgo) and c.ReportYear = Year(@12MonthsAgo)
This is for an year ago. In the same way if i have to get the previous month and current month, can i do that with in the same query by setting the filters ? how do we do that ?

Is there a better way other than i end up writing 3 select queries and then putting the select to a tmp table and later merging the tables ?

```
create table #TPTABLE
(
    KPIName varchar(150)
    ,MetricName Varchar(200)
    ,MetricId INT
    ,DataSource varchar(50)
    ,[AnYearAgo] Float
    ,[PreviousMonth]  float
    ,[CurrentMonth] float
);


insert into #TPTABLE 
(KPIName,MetricName,MetricId,DataSource,[AnYearAgo])
SELECT
     p.KPIName
    ,p.MetricName
    ,p.MetricId
    ,p.DataSource
    ,c.Value as [AnYearAgo]
    FROM [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMetricDetails] p
    LEFT JOIN [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMectricValues] c
    ON p.[MetricId] = c.MetricId
    WHERE c.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @12MonthsAgo) and c.ReportYear = Year(@12MonthsAgo) 
    ORDER BY KPI_Id ASC, [MetricId] ASC
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with "Year Ago , Previous Month and Current Month" but it sounds like you need to convert the 3 fields to a proper ``datetime`` (or ``datetime2``) and calculate based on that.

Comment: Date format is not a problem. I have all the calculation to get the previous year,current year last year.    
12MonthsAgo AS DATE = DATEADD(mm, -12, ReportDate),                
12PreviousMonth AS DATE = DATEADD(mm, -1, ReportDate);                 

My Problem here is in the where clause we give this calculated date as filter Like
WHERE c.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @12MonthsAgo) and c.ReportYear = Year(@12MonthsAgo)

Comment: Same manner for current month and previous month.                  To do that i have to write 2 more select and update the result table. So my question is , is there a better way than to write 2 more select. Can we do this with in a single query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
     p.KPIName
    ,p.MetricName
    ,p.MetricId
    ,p.DataSource
    ,c.Value
    ,c2.Value
    ,c3.Value
    FROM [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMetricDetails] p
    LEFT JOIN [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMectricValues] c
    ON p.[MetricId] = c.MetricId
        AND c.[CommissionerCode] = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Commissioner, ''), c.[CommissionerCode])
        ANd ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @12MonthsAgo) and c.ReportYear = Year(@12MonthsAgo)
    LEFT JOIN [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMectricValues] c2
    ON p.[MetricId] = c2.MetricId
        AND c2.[CommissionerCode] = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Commissioner, ''), c2.[CommissionerCode])
        ANd c2.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @PreviousMonth) and c2.ReportYear = Year(@PreviousMonth)
    LEFT JOIN [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMectricValues] c3
    ON p.[MetricId] = c3.MetricId
        AND c3.[CommissionerCode] = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Commissioner, ''), c3.[CommissionerCode])
        ANd c3.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @PreviousMonth) and c3.ReportYear = Year(@PreviousMonth)
    ORDER BY p.KPI_Id ASC, p.[MetricId] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
insert into #TPTABLE 
(KPIName,MetricName,MetricId,DataSource,[AnYearAgo])
SELECT
    KPIName
    ,MetricName
    ,MetricId
    ,DataSource
    ,[AnYearAgo]
    ,[PreviousMonth]
    ,[CurrentMonth]
FROM (
    SELECT
        KPIName
        ,MetricName
        ,MetricId
        ,DataSource
        ,KPI_Id
        ,sum(case when c.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @12MonthsAgo) and c.ReportYear = Year(@12MonthsAgo) then c.Value else 0 end) as [AnYearAgo]
        ,sum(case when c.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @PreviousMonth) and c.ReportYear = Year(@PreviousMonth) then c.Value else 0 end) as [PreviousMonth]
        ,sum(case when c.ReportMonth = DATENAME(month, @CurrentMonth) and c.ReportYear = Year(@CurrentMonth) then c.Value else 0 end) as [CurrentMonth]
    FROM [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMetricDetails] p
    LEFT JOIN [IntegratedCare].[report].[KPIMectricValues] c
    ON p.[MetricId] = c.MetricId
    GROUP BY KPIName, MetricName, MetricId, DataSource, KPI_Id
ORDER BY KPI_Id ASC, [MetricId] ASC
```